# Apache , NodeJs, Server Sent Events

Tags: node.js, apache, apache2, server-sent-events

First of all, I know (**Putting Node under Apache**) this is not the approach to go but due to time constraint I cannot experiment.
I am trying to use Server Sent events for a mobile application. After reading all over Net, I figured out that **Nodejs** is the server to go for. My 80/443 port is occupied by Apache Web server, so I want Node To run behind Apache.

The Problems which I am facing are:-
1. I am not able to get the **close/end** events on refreshing browser or closing browser rather I get after a fixed certain amount of delay, so not able to maintain when the client shuts down connection in Nodejs.

```
req.on("close", function() {
    removeConnection(res);
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

2. Apache is sending **Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100** which I dont want as I want client to be connected forever till anyone closes connection, due to this Browser automatically closes connection and I start getting **net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING**. How Can I modify this value only for Node Proxy Requests.
I have added 
ProxyPass /events http://localhost:5000/events

ProxyPassReverse /events http://localhost:5000/events
**Response Headers**
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:key,origin, x-requested-with, content-   type,Accept,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/event-stream; charset=utf-8
custom:header
Date:Wed, 13 Jan 2016 18:12:48 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Express

**Note:-** All this is happening when I am using Apache to proxy to Node, else if I directly hit Node (which I cannot in prod due to blocked port) everything works fine.

Comment: Why don't you just serve SSE on a non standard port, like 8100? Best solution is to just spin up a cloud server just for Node. Don't mix the use of servers.

Comment: @baynezy As of now I am doing that but the problem is its not a good solution to get ports open for every other solution. I found that Enabling Node under NGINX is better. So, should i change my apche to NGINX??

Comment: I agree. Which is why the best solution is to install node on it's own server.

Answer (score 0):

The KeepAlive settings by default allowed only in server or virtual host configuration.

But during the request processing, apache2 use environment variables (based on apache configuration) to determine the current settings.

Fortunately with mod_rewrite, you can alter apache environment variables on request basis, so you can disable keepalive on specific request.

For example:

```
#Load rewrite module
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

#Enable mod_rewrite functionality
RewriteEngine On

#rewrite rule inside locationmatch
<LocationMatch ".*\/sse\/.*">
   #This is not required, used only for debug purposes
   Header set X-Intelligence "KEEPALIVEOFF"       
   #Here goes the mod rewrite environment variable trick
   RewriteRule .* - [E=nokeepalive:1]
</LocationMatch>
```